# how to Export RDLC to excel with cell format

Tags: c#, export-to-excel, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I am exporting RDLC to excel, I have id , joining date field in rdlc. I have set tablix Id textbox  as "number" and for joining date as "date" . But in excel the format cells for id is  showing as general instead of number.

How to make format cells for id column as number

Answer (score 0):

When defining `TextBox` formatting, try with the Custom format.
If your ID is an integer, just set custom format to zero, like this:

[image: like this.]

After that, you can click again on "Number" and see how it is represented as a number without decimal places, like this:

[image: like this.]

The rest is easy: From `ReportViewer`, save the report as Excel. The format of the ID column should be Custom, but it is actually numeric. Honestly, I don’t know why Excel says it is a Custom format and not a number, but I wouldn’t worry about that.

For more info about Excel Number formatting check this out:
[Number Formatting in Excel - All You Need to Know (spreadsheetweb.com)](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/number-formatting-excel/)